# Time based criteria action without modifying record

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I have this scenario where the opportunity might remain untouched for a while. TO preven the opportunity from falling through the cracks, I want to send an email alert if the opportunity remains open for 90 days.

If I set a time based workflow to fire 90 days after opp creation day, then if someone DOES close this opportunity, does the time based workflow rule fire?

It shouldn't but just making sure. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the Time-Based Workflow FAQ (Knowledge Article Number 000005245) (emphasis mine):

> #### [Will the pending actions in the queue ALWAYS trigger?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005245&type=1)
>
> No. Time-dependent actions remain in the Workflow Queue until processed or the rule criteria for the Workflow Rule are evaluated as "false." **If a record no longer matches the rule criteria when the rule is evaluated, Salesforce removes the time-dependent actions queued for that record.**
>
> - Example: An Opportunity Workflow Rule may specify:
>
>   - A criteria set to "Opportunity: Status not equals to Closed Won, Closed Lost."
>   - An associated time-dependent action with a time trigger set to 7 days before the Opportunity close date. If a record matching the criteria is created on July 1st and the Close Date is set to July 30th, the time-dependent action is scheduled for July 23rd. However, if the Opportunity is set to "Closed Won" or "Closed Lost" before July 23rd, the time-dependent action is automatically removed from the queue.

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for.